# Dynamically change begin on limitTo filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to have the `begin` parameter in the `limitTo` filter change dynamically, thus creating paging?

First thing I tried was

```
limitTo: 10 : (pagination.current - 1) * 10
```

Which didn't work when `pagination.current` changed.

Then I tried

```
limitTo: 10 : pagination.skip
```

Again, where in my controller, `pagination.skip` was changed.

Is this possible? Or do I have to create my own filter for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`begin`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/docs/api/ng/filter/limitTo) parameter of the `limitTo` filter is a feature in Angular 1.4+ (currently in beta). [`limitTo` in Angular 1.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/service/$filter) and earlier don't have that parameter.

If you need the `begin` parameter on an earlier Angular version then you will need to make your own filter to support that.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that in the documentation.